# MockMvcResultMatchers accepts incompatible content types

Tags: spring, spring-boot, content-type, spring-test

Testing method expecting **application/json;charset=UTF-8:**

```
@Test
public void testSuccessfullStatusGetUserByID() throws Exception {
    mockMVC.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/users/1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
}
```

This test succeeds even though the actual response is **application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8:**
[image]

**pom.xml:**

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Framework are you using?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE